# Null pointer exception in hadoop reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am facing the `NullPointerException` with the below code. It would be great if some one can review and help me with the program.

The mapper is running fine but, I get an NPE, when I am try to split the value at the iterator. Please help me figure out my mistake. I have attached the mapper out below.

**Toppermain.java**

```
package TopperPackage;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;


public class TopperMain {
//hadoop jar worcount.jar ars[0] args[1]
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Job myhadoopJob = new Job();

myhadoopJob.setJarByClass(TopperMain.class);
myhadoopJob.setJobName("Finding topper based on subject");

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(myhadoopJob, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(myhadoopJob, new Path(args[1]));

myhadoopJob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
myhadoopJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

myhadoopJob.setMapperClass(TopperMapper.class);
myhadoopJob.setReducerClass(TopperReduce.class);


myhadoopJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
myhadoopJob.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
myhadoopJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
myhadoopJob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(myhadoopJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}

}
```

---

**TopperMapper.java**

```
package TopperPackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
/*Surender,87,60,50,50,80
Raj,80,70,80,85,60
Anten,81,60,50,70,100
Dinesh,60,90,80,80,70
Priya,80,85,91,60,75
*/
public class TopperMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>

{
String temp,temp2;

protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
String record = value.toString();
String[] parts = record.split(",");
temp=parts[0];

temp2=temp+ "\t" + parts[1];
context.write(new Text("Tamil"),new Text(temp2));
temp2=temp+ "\t" + parts[2];
context.write(new Text("English"),new Text(temp2));

temp2=temp+ "\t" + parts[3];
context.write(new Text("Maths"),new Text(temp2));

temp2=temp+ "\t" + parts[4];
context.write(new Text("Science"),new Text(temp2));

temp2=temp+ "\t" + parts[5];
context.write(new Text("SocialScrience"),new Text(temp2));


       }
}
```

---

**TopperReduce.java**

```
package TopperPackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;



public class TopperReduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
int temp;
private String[] names;
private int[] marks;
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
String top = "";
int count =0,topmark;
marks = null;
String befsplit;
String[] parts=null;
names = null;
for (Text t : values)
{
befsplit= t.toString();
parts = befsplit.split("\t");
names[count]=parts[0];
marks[count]=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
count = count+1;

}
topmark=calcTopper(marks);
top=names[topmark]+ "\t"+marks[topmark]  ;
context.write(new Text(key), new Text(top));
}
public int calcTopper(int[] marks)
{
int count=marks.length;
temp=((marks[1]));
int i=0;
for (i=1;i<=(count-2);i++)
{
   if(temp < marks[i+1])
   {
   temp = marks[i+1];

   }

}
return i;
}
}
```

the error is

```
cloudera@cloudera-vm:~/Jarfiles$ hadoop jar TopperMain.jar /user/cloudera/inputfiles/topper/topperinput.txt /user/cloudera/outputfiles/topper/
14/08/24 23:17:07 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/08/24 23:17:08 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/24 23:17:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201408241907_0012
14/08/24 23:17:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/08/24 23:17:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/08/24 23:18:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408241907_0012_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TopperPackage.TopperReduce.reduce(TopperReduce.java:25)
    at TopperPackage.TopperReduce.reduce(TopperReduce.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201408241907_0012_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201408241907_0012_r_000000_0: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
14/08/24 23:18:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201408241907_0012_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TopperPackage.TopperReduce.reduce(TopperReduce.java:25)
    at TopperPackage.TopperReduce.reduce(TopperReduce.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201408241907_0012_r_000000_1: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201408241907_0012_r_000000_1: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I am getting the expected output from mapper but reducer is throwing error when splitting the output and storing in a variable.

The mapper output is

```
Tamil   Surender    87
English Surender    60
Maths   Surender    50
Science Surender    50
SocialScrience  Surender    80
Tamil   Raj 80
English Raj 70
Maths   Raj 80
Science Raj 85
SocialScrience  Raj 60
Tamil   Anten   81
English Anten   60
Maths   Anten   50
Science Anten   70
SocialScrience  Anten   100
Tamil   Dinesh  60
English Dinesh  90
Maths   Dinesh  80
Science Dinesh  80
SocialScrience  Dinesh  70
Tamil   Priya   80
English Priya   85
Maths   Priya   91
Science Priya   60
SocialScrience  Priya   75
```

Any advice to point out my mistake is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to you are initializing **marks** and **names** arrays to **null** and not initialize them properly. Please use the below reducer class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
public class TopperReduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    int temp;
    private String[] names = new String[10];
    private int[] marks = new int[10];

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String top = "";
        int count = 0, topmark;
        String befsplit;
        String[] parts = null;
        for (Text t : values) {
           befsplit = t.toString();
           parts = befsplit.split("\t");
           names[count] = parts[0];
           marks[count] = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
           count++;
        }
       topmark = calcTopper(marks);
       top = names[topmark] + "\t" + marks[topmark];
        context.write(new Text(key), new Text(top));
   }

public int calcTopper(int[] marks) {
    int count = marks.length;
    int i = 0;
    int highestMArk = 0;
    int mark = 0;
    int highestMarkIndex = 0;
    for (; i < count; i++) {
        mark = marks[i];
        if (mark > highestMArk) {
            highestMarkIndex = i;

        }
    }
    return highestMarkIndex;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a null array variable parts so you are getting this error, 
change your code as i mentioned below it could work

```
 public class TopperReduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
int temp;
private String[] names=new String[20];
private int[] marks= new int[20];
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
String top = "";
int count =0,topmark;
for (Text t : values)
{
String befsplit= t.toString();
String[] parts = befsplit.split("\t");
names[count]=parts[0];
marks[count]=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
count = count+1;

}
topmark=calcTopper(marks);
top=names[topmark]+ "\t"+marks[topmark]  ;
context.write(new Text(key), new Text(top));
}
```